# Can't change txt file name in python

Tags: python

I need to rename some TXT files with the contents of the first line of the file, but when I run the code below, I get the following error:

> "PermissionError: [WinError 32]The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

```py
import os
from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta

id = 4577809
data_hoje = date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
data = date.today().strftime('%d%m%Y')

caminho_remuneracao = os.listdir(f"C:\\Users\\{id}\\OneDrive\\Onedrive - GPA")

for arquivo in caminho_remuneracao:
    if 'GPARH_0030' in arquivo:
        if data in arquivo:
            with open(arquivo, "a+") as arq:
                linhas = arq.readline()
                linha = (linhas[5:19])
                nome = f'GPA_PEDD_{linha}_{data}'
                os.rename(arquivo, nome)
                print(f'arquivo {arquivo} renomeado para {nome}')aminho_remuneracao = os.listdir(f"C:\\Users\\{id}\\OneDrive\\Onedrive - GPA")
```

Comment: you are opening `arquivo` when you do `with open(arquivo, "a+") as arq:`  so inside you cannot rename it while you have it open. put the rename outside the `with` block

Comment: You have to either close the file before renaming it or create a copy with the name that you want before closing and removing the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rename it outside the with block. Try this:

```
import os
from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta

id = 4577809
data_hoje = date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
data = date.today().strftime('%d%m%Y')

caminho_remuneracao = os.listdir(f"C:\\Users\\{id}\\OneDrive\\Onedrive - GPA")


for arquivo in caminho_remuneracao:
    if 'GPARH_0030' in arquivo:
        if data in arquivo:
            with open(arquivo, "a+") as arq:
                linhas = arq.readline()
                linha = (linhas[5:19])
                nome = f'GPA_PEDD_{linha}_{data}'
            os.rename(arquivo, nome)
            print(f'arquivo {arquivo} renomeado para {nome}')
```

Comment: When replacing the code returns the following error: FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Unable to create an existing file: 'GPARH_0030_D_01022023024401_VR.txt' -> 'GPA_PEDD__01022023'

Comment: are you sure a file with the new name doesn't exist already?

Comment: I'm sure, I just looked at the folder again

Comment: Now it worked, when using the writing method, the contents of the files were updated and all the data was deleted, when doing so, it created a file with the name "GPA_PEDD__01022023" with nothing, that's why the message that the file already existed in the directory , sorry for the mistake, I already put your answer as a solution, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

When you call `os.rename()`, you are calling it within your `with open()` loop.
You cannot rename the file because the `with open()` loop is currently using it; try moving the `os.rename()` outside of this loop.

Try the following:

```py
for arquivo in caminho_remuneracao:
    if 'GPARH_0030' in arquivo:
        if data in arquivo:
            nome=""
            with open(arquivo, "a+") as arq:
                linhas = arq.readline()
                linha = (linhas[5:19])
                nome = f'GPA_PEDD_{linha}_{data}'
            os.rename(arquivo, nome)
            print(f'arquivo {arquivo} renomeado para {nome}')
```

Comment: When replacing the code returns the following error: FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Unable to create an existing file: 'GPARH_0030_D_01022023024401_VR.txt' -> 'GPA_PEDD__01022023'

Answer (score 0):

**with** is your problem

```
for arquivo in caminho_remuneracao:
    if 'GPARH_0030' in arquivo:
        if data in arquivo:
            arq=open(arquivo, "a+")
            linhas = arq.readline()
            arq.close()
            nome = f'GPA_PEDD_{linhas[5:19]}_{data}'
            os.rename(arquivo, nome)
            print(f'arquivo {arquivo}
```